# How to get multiple files name using xslt

Tags: xslt

How to get multiple files name using xslt

I am using collection function

```
        <xsl:for-each select="collection('file:///D:/Xlst/Session 06/05-collection/?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')">
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that the query parameters to `collection` you use are Saxon specific I assume you use some version of Saxon. Saxon since 9.8/2017 supports XSLT 3.0 with XPath 3.1 functions where you additionally have a function `uri-collection` so there it might be easier to use

```
    <xsl:for-each select="uri-collection('file:///D:/Xlst/Session 06/05-collection/?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')"> 
       <xsl:message expand-text="yes">Current URI: {.}; file name: {tokenize(., '/')[last()]}</xsl:message>
       ..
       <xsl:apply-templates select="doc(.)"/>
       ..
    </xsl:for-each>
```

But you haven't explained in detail which file names you are looking for and how your posted code fails or uses the collection.